# Enable php cli to run files starting with <? and <?php

Tags: php, command-line-interface

This is a very elementary question but I have not been able to find a solution for some time now.

I have a large code base in php. Some files start with `<?` others start with `<?php`.

When I run files with `<?php` starters run perfectly however php-cli does not recognize `<?` as a php file and instead prints it on `stdout`. How do I get it to run both types of files. I am using php version 5.3.27.

Comment: short_open_tags directive in the php.ini file

Comment: And why not upgrade to a version of PHP that is still actively supported

Comment: @MarkBaker to be fair, 5.3.27 is only a year old. I've seen too many boxes still running PHP 4.

Comment: @MarkBaker Not in my hand actually. A lot of files are 5.3 compliant. Rewriting would be tedious.